# How do I connect a 3rd computer to a subnet using a port the 2nd computer, so that the 1st computer can communicate directly to the 3rd?

Tags: linux, centos, networking, routing, networkmanager

Sorry for the terribly worded question.

I have 3 CentOS 9 Steam computers (PC1, PC2, PC3), and I want to configure it so that PC1 can communicate (ssh, nfs, rpc) directly to PC3. I'm not physically able to connect PC1 directly to PC3 through a switch, so my idea it to just use an extra port on PC2 as a  kind of switch and keep PC3 on the same subnet.

```
   PC1                 PC2                 PC3     
         196.1.1.2     196.1.1.3           196.1.1.102
   +-------------+     +-------------+     +-------------+
   |         eth0|-----|eth3     eth4|-----|eth0         |
   |             |     |             |     |             |
   |             |     |             |     |             |
   |             |     |             |     |             |
   |         eth1|-+   |             |     |             | 
   +-------------+ |   +-------------+     +-------------+
                   |
              DHCP Internet
```

I am using NetworkManager with ifcfg-ethX for the configurations. PC1(eth0) and PC2(eth3) are basically identical, but I don't know how to configure PC2(eth4) and PC3(eth0).

```
DEVICE=eth0
IPADDR=196.1.1.2
HWADDR=xx
NM_CONTROLLED=yes
ONBOOT=yes
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
PREFIX=24
DEFROUTE=no
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
```

My application requires P3 to mount a P1 NFS and have tiRPC communication. Connecting P3 directly to P1 through a switch works great (hence my desire to keep on the same subnet). This is not possible in some locations, so I need to use PC2 to connect to PC3. I know it's possible to just add another switch there, but it seems unnecessary since PC2 already has a beautiful empty port right there.

Connecting PC2 to PC3 on a different subnet works fine, and then PC1 can connect to PC3 over an ssh tunnel. However, I could not get the nfs/rpc to work properly, so I'm hoping that maybe **eth4** on PC2 could basically just be a switch to connect PC3 to the same subnet?

I'm pretty sure I need to enable ipv4 forwarding on PC2 and add some routing info. Beyond that, I'm don't know how to actually configure it. Ideally I could just set it up in the ifcfg-ethX files.

Comment: as a start, I'd bridge eth3/eth4 - but I think that won't be enough, I've never cobbled together a network like this. I mean, PC3 requires PC2 to be up and running to be useful

Comment: Your best option is to use a switch.  If you don't already have one, you can buy cheap 4 to 8 port gigabit switches for very little money (starting from about $20-$30 USD).   Otherwise, as @JaromandaX says, bridge eth3 & eth4 on PC2 and accept the fact that PC3 will rely on PC2 being up and running for network access.

Comment: I second bridging `eth3` and `eth4`. You'll need to assign `196.1.1.3` to the bridge interface, typically `br0` etc. Google for "linux create bridge" or similar, there should be plenty tutorials and explanations of how that works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try bridging and provide an update. Other clarifications: PC1 and PC2 need to be running. If either are down then PC3 doesn't really even matter. Switch is not ideal due to operating conditions (placement/quality) & quantity.

Comment: Just for clarity, you would "need to enable ipv4 forwarding on PC2 and add some routing info" in order to "get the nfs/rpc to work properly" by "Connecting PC2 to PC3 on a different subnet".  You don't necessarily need IP forwarding and additional routing for a bridged setup.